# SSMTP SSL connection null

Tags: 16.04, ssl, tls, ssmtp

Installed ssmtp on Xenial. Trying to send through gmail.  When attempting to send a test message, syslog shows

```
Jun 24 07:42:19 YYYY sSMTP[30547]: Creating SSL connection to host

Jun 24 07:42:19 YYYY sSMTP[30547]: Invalid response: 501 5.5.4  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=helo u18sm609381ywg.15 - gsmtp (XXXX@gmail.com)

Jun 24 07:42:19 YYYY sSMTP[30547]: SSL connection using (null)

Jun 24 07:42:19 YYYY sSMTP[30547]: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
```

XXXX and YYYY are specifics to my setup.  I suspect I have a TLS or SSL problem since I see "SSL connection using (null)"  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have configured your server to identify itself as `u18sm609381ywg.15` in the HELO command.  You need to use a valid `FQDN` (Fully Qualified Domain Name) or a domain literal in the form `[192.0.2.14]`.  As you are using port 587, you likely also need to authenticate with your gmail id.